# How to get quantities of comments even quantity of comments equals 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table posts, and tables comments. Comment have filed "post_id" which referencer to posts's filed "id". I want to get quantities of comments for each posts. I use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count 
FROM comments 
WHERE post_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
GROUP BY id HAVING count >= 0 ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC
```

But he returns only quantity > 0, but I need to get quantities of comments which also equals 0.

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: change GROUP BY id HAVING count >= 0  to GROUP BY id HAVING count(id) >= 0

Comment: check my answer, it's work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's count on null

Check this

```
SELECT COUNT(post_id) AS 'count'
FROM posts LEFT JOIN comments on post.id = comments.post_id
WHERE post.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY count DESC, created_at DESC
```

You need to get posts from `posts` table , some posts don't have comments so the `post_id` not exist in `comments`

Comment: Nope. All same.

Comment: All same maybe you group by wrong column, please show me your table

Comment: Comments : https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2riK.png
Posts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhuSH.png

Comment: please check last edited. use left join to get all posts not exists in table comments

Answer (score 0):

`Having` will not help in this case. It looks like you do not have any comments for some posts. So, you will not select any record for this post from comments table. You need something like this:

```
select p.id, count(c.id)
from posts p 
left join comments c on p.id = c.post_id
where p.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

Comment: I do not need to connect tables

Comment: @Cannon431 So, how you want to select record for some post_id, if in table there is no any record for it?

Comment: If you need receive full `id: count` list from query, you need use `join`. 
In other way, you can just initialize `{'id': .., 'count': 0}` dict in code and update all positive results from query.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(post_id)
FROM comment
WHERE post_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(post_id) >= 0 
ORDER BY created_at DESC, post_id DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this query:

```
select p.post_id, count(c.id) as total_comments
from posts p LEFT JOIN comments c
on p.post_id = c.id
group by p.post_id
order by p.post_id desc;
```

Illustration:

```
select * from posts;
+----------+---------+
| postdesc | post_id |
+----------+---------+
| post-1   |       1 |
| post-2   |       2 |
| post-3   |       3 |
+----------+---------+

select * from comments;
+--------------+------+------------+
| comment_desc | id   | created_at |
+--------------+------+------------+
| comment-1    |    1 | 2018-04-01 |
| comment-2    |    1 | 2018-04-02 |
| comment-3    |    2 | 2018-04-03 |
| comment-4    |    1 | 2018-04-04 |
+--------------+------+------------+

--query
+---------+----------------+
| post_id | total_comments |
+---------+----------------+
|       3 |              0 |
|       2 |              1 |
|       1 |              3 |
+---------+----------------+
```

**Update**: Here is a version that does not use JOIN syntax. Gives the same result as above.

```
select a.post_id, a.total_comments 
from
(
    select post_id, 0 as total_comments
    from posts
    where post_id not in 
        (
            select distinct id 
            from comments
        )
    union
    select id, count(*)
    from comments
    group by id
) a
order by a.post_id desc;
```

Comment: I do not need to connect tables

Comment: Connecting the tables is necessary to know which `post_ids` are in `posts` table that do not have any comments in `comments` table. For example, in the above illustration, `post_id=3` does not have any comments in `comments` table. Without connecting them, we can't get `total_comments=0` for `post_id=3` in result. Are you looking to avoid a join syntax?

Comment: Updated my answer to include a version that does not use the JOIN syntax.

Comment: I avoid join , because I need to get separately posts and comments. Because Im need to cache posts , but not quantity of comments

Comment: Ok, see if the non-join syntax is more appropriate for your case. I posted an edit with the alternate query.

Comment: not working. Error: #1054 - Unknown column 'post_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Ensure you have `post_id` column in `posts` table. Please check the schema I posted in answer for `posts` and `comments` table that the query is using. If your column names are different, please update them in the query.